# Blending Colors after Image Trace - Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, image-trace

I've used image trace to turn a `.png` file into a vector image but some of the colors in the sky background look kind of off. Is there a way that I can blend the shades of blue in the sky so that it doesn't look weird?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried re-tracing the image with different settings (e.g. a greater number of colors)?  If that doesn't help, I would delete the sky (apart from the clouds), place a rectangle below all of your other layers (clouds, trees, grass, etc.), fill that rectangle with a dark to light blue gradient.

Answer (score 1):

You could delete the sky shapes and add your own.

Or you could add additional objects if desired.

Or you could select the shapes and change their color.

After the trace (and expand) they are just standard Illustrator objects.